В чём проблема с открытием phpMyAdmin из ispmanager
Загрузил чистую панель ispmanager. После того, как создал сайт, решил проблемы с ssh и прочим перешёл к БД. Само БД открывается, в том числе и через консоль, однако при нажатии "Web-интерфейс БД" в ispmanager даёт пустую страницу с надписью "Type: 'rpc' Object: 'query' Value: 'query: Couldn't connect to server'".
СУБД - MySql
Настройки сервера и ошибка ниже.


